# gensim Word2vec transfer learning (from a non-gensim model)

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim

I have a set of embeddings trained with a neural network that has nothing to do with gensim's word2vec.

I want to use these embeddings as the initial weights in `gensim.Word2vec`.

Now what I did see is that I can `model.load(SOME_MODEL)` and then continue training, but it requires a gensim modle as input. Also `reset_from()` seems to only accept other gensim model.
But in my case, I don't have a gensim model to start from, but a text file in word2vec format of embeddings.

So how do I start transfer learning from an word2vec text file to `gensim.Word2vec`?

Answer (score 1):

You can load other models using the key vector format of the original Word2Vec model

```
import io

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

# first line is vocab size and vector dim
model_buf = io.StringIO("""
2 3
word0 -0.000737 -0.002106 0.001851
word1 -0.000878 -0.002106 0.002834
""".lstrip())

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_buf, binary=False)

model['word0']
```

Comment: I need to continue training, I tried `model = Word2Vec(); model.wv.load_word2vec_format(filename); model.train(... )` but it doesn't work

Comment: You'd do something like this: : model.build_vocab(new_sentences, update=True)
model.train(new_sentences)

Comment: @bluesummers build_vocab and train are part of Word2Vec. You'll have to figure out how to turn `model` in the example above from a `KeyedVectors` to a `Word2Vec` instance.